# Which EU-related jurisdictions in Americas apply the GDPR regulation?

Tags: gdpr

According to some information, a person will need to be a resident in an EU country in order to be protected by the GDPR regulation.

Are there jurisdictions in North or South America where residency similarly conveys GDPR protection for EU citizens?

Comment: GDPR does not trigger on citizenship or residency status. Processing activities are subject to the GDPR when an EU establishment of the Data Controller is involved, or when Data Subjects who are physically in the EU are tracked, or when the Data Controller offers their services in the EU. Consequently, you are GDPR-protected anywhere on the world when interacting with EU Data Controllers.

Comment: @amon, are you saying that if I as a EU citizen go to USA, I will be GDPR protected there as well (at least if dealing with any US organizations/corporations that have a EU presence)?

Comment: No, per Art 2 data processing of multinational companies is only subject to the GDPR when the processing is “in the context of the activities of an [EU] establishment” of the data controller. So a person is not protected when they interact with the US branch of a company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various bits of France which are not actually in Europe.  Several of them are in the Caribbean, and French Guiana is in South America.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_state_territories_and_the_European_Union#French_overseas_departments).  These are parts of the EU (although not part of Schengen or the EU VAT Area), so residency will grant protection under GDPR.